# getting effect sizes from a quasibinomial glm

Tags: r, glm

I have some data that I've fit a glm from the family quasibinomial. The model shows high significance for a number of different factors. However, I was wondering how can I get effect sizes for these different factors. Does anyone have any idea?

The model results:

```
Call:
glm(formula = freq ~ K + res_dist + K:trail_cost + trail_cost:res_dist:K, 
    family = "quasibinomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2072  -0.3505  -0.1406   0.2714   1.7746  

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  1.222e+00  1.786e-01   6.842 7.24e-11 ***
K                           -1.741e-05  2.107e-06  -8.265 1.19e-14 ***
res_distrandom              -1.419e+00  2.386e-01  -5.949 1.02e-08 ***
K:trail_cost                 1.381e-01  3.930e-02   3.515 0.000531 ***
K:res_distrandom:trail_cost  1.564e-01  2.532e-02   6.176 3.03e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.2932451)

    Null deviance: 126.028  on 230  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  66.616  on 226  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: How is the effect size different than the estimated coefficient already given in the output? What exactly does your data look like? These don't look like traditional R "factors" in your model.

Comment: sorry should have been more clear. res_dist is a factor, K and trail_cost are both continuous variables. The estimated coefficients aren't directly effect sizes as I understand it. Certainly that wouldn't really make sense as the output can only be between 0 and 1, so an effect of -1.419 for res_distrandom wouldn't really make sense

Comment: Are you sure `class(data$res_dist)` returns “factor”. I would expect the output to look different if that were the case. Glms model a transformed response. I’m still not sure how you want to report effect sizes.

Comment: Yes it does return factor. Why would you expect different? This seems pretty standard to me? Ah right ok, but how can I transform the coeffecients to give something meaningful: e.g. the effect of res_dist being random is an increase by xx in the output

Comment: When I do `dd <- data.frame(cat=sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace = TRUE), num=rnorm(50), y=rbeta(50, 2, 1)); glm(y~cat+num, dd, family = "quasibinomial")` `, R shows me a value for each of the levels of `cat`, not just an overall value and just one value for `num` since it's numeric. I don't understand why you are seeing different output.

Comment: @MrFlick if there are only two levels to a factor then you will only get a single output as it is comparing one to the other. One of them has to be a 'reference level' so you only get the output for one.

Comment: @Dom_Burns are you talking about odds ratios? You can extract them with `exp(coef(x))` (but also check out this: www.rdocumentation.org/packages/questionr/versions/0.6.3/topics/odds.ratio). Simply put, if you have an odds ratio (OR) of 1 you have no effect of x on y, if you have OR > 1, there's a positive association, and if you have OR < 1, it's negative. Not sure if that's what you were looking for.